# Different UI elements are Drawn at the same coordinates, but never intersect?why?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

In a customised `View`, as shown in the code below, I am drawing a `point` at a specific location on the screen, and then I draw an `oval` that should pass on the same `point` I drew. But, the problem is, despite the `oval` is started to be drawn at the same (x,y) of that `point`, surprisingly, the `oval` does not pass on that `point`, it is getting drawn a little bit lower than the point.

Code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    RectF oval = new RectF();

    ovalTop = screenW/2;
    ovalLeft = screenH/2;
    ovalBottom = (ovalTop + 100);
    ovalRight = ovalLeft + 100;

    canvas.drawPoint(ovalTop, ovalLeft, mArcPaint);
    oval.set(ovalTop, ovalLeft, ovalBottom, ovalRight);
    canvas.drawOval(oval, mOvalPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, 270, false, mArcPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `point` you mean the upper left corner of the rectangle including your oval.
Which (quite obviously) is **not** part of the oval circumference.

If you want to **center** your oval onto that point, you should move the origin by -50x and -50y
(a -50 offset is needed, because your oval is 100w by 100h):

```
oval.set(ovalTop - 50, ovalLeft - 50, ovalBottom, ovalRight);
```

Comment: Thank you, now I figured it out.